# How do I define the current time in bot-framework-composer?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

All I need to know is how to set a property to the current time in bot-framework-composer (London, British Summer Time not UTC). Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while for some reason but the answer I figured out was addHours(utcNow(), 1)